# Problem while using multiple conditions in a 'while loop'

Tags: c, while-loop

So, I'm just starting to learn the C language and coding in general. I was learning about
'while loops' in C and came across this problem while making a guessing game (idea from the internet).
Here's the code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main(){
    int answer = 10;
    int guess[2];
    int i = 0;
    int remaningGuesses = 3;
    while(guess[i-1] != answer && remaningGuesses != 0){
        printf("Remaining guesses %d.Enter a number: ", remaningGuesses);
        scanf("%d", &guess[i]);
        i++;
        remaningGuesses = remaningGuesses - 1;
    }
        printf("%d\n", i);
   
    printf("%d\n", guess[i-1]);
    printf("%d\n", answer);     
       
    /*alright i see the problem now. the value of 'answer' changes to 'guess[i-1]', though i don't know y.*/
    
    if(guess[i-1] = answer){
        printf("Your answer is right");
    }else{
        printf("Your answer is wrong");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After much time I discovered that the value of 'answer' was changing to 'guess[i-1]'. What I don't understand is, how it could be happening.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Though I suspect it was got something to do with the multiple conditions in the condition part of the 'while loop'.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you expect to happen for `i==0` in first iteration? What memory will be accessed in `guess[i-1]`? What are allowed index values for `int guess[2]`?

Comment: Why do you store each number in an array? You only need the last input. If you need all numbers, 3 guesses do not fit into an array of 2 elements.

Comment: Typo: `if(guess[i-1] = answer)` should be `if(guess[i-1] == answer)`

Comment: Weather Vane, that happened by mistake. It's '==' in the actual code

Comment: That is why you must copy/paste the actual code. It's now in doubt how many *other* typos there are.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to fix those typos. Also use `@username` to reply to users, otherwise they don't get notifications.

Comment: You state "changing the 'answer' to 'guess[i-1]'". Three loops has caused `scanf()` to jam the 3rd guess beyond the end of the arrary.... Note: the compiler is free to allocate stack addresses as it sees fit... From your comment, it would seem that 'answer' was the victim of overrunning 'guess'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking undefined behaviour.

For an array with 2 elements you may access elements with index `0` or `1`.
Your loop starts with index `-1`. This is an out of bounds access causing undefined behaivour.
This is not at all related to using multiple subexpressions in your condition.

Second error is that you store up to 3 guesses but only provide memory for 2 values in your array.

Third error: You compare the guess with the answer already before you even tried to read the first guess. In case you accidentally access `answer` via illegal array index, this would cause the loop to exit already before first iteration as it actually compares `answer != answer` which is `false`.

Comment: Ah oh. That's quite silly of me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user15672273 If you don't need any more help, you can press the checkmark next to an answer to mark your question as solved.